# How to insert infinte scroll on woocommerce product loop

Tags: woocommerce, infinite-scroll

i have a cusom shop page . In which i displayed product based on category .
For example category names are car , bus, boat etc

So in my custom shop page i write the following html .

```
<div class="main-block">
 <h2>car</h2>
 <p>Description</p>
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="50" columns="4" category="car"]'); ?>    
</div>

<div class="main-block">
 <h2>Bus</h2>
 <p>Description</p>
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="50" columns="4" category="bus"]'); ?>    
</div>

<div class="main-block">
 <h2>Boat</h2>
 <p>Description</p>
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="50" columns="4" category="boat"]'); ?>   
</div>
```

Everything is working fine , but the problem is page load time increase . So i am planing to change the load method . Instead of loading all 50 products from each category , first load 8 products, then user scroll down then load other products like .

How can i modify the code for this ? Please help .

If anyone have experienced same problem before please help to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick way to solve this problem is using

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

and replace `[products limit="50" columns="4" category="car"]` with

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="product" columns="4" css_classes="products" posts_per_page="4" transition="fade"  taxonomy="product_cat" taxonomy_terms="car" taxonomy_operator="IN" button_label=""]
```

for more read https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/

or

if you need a detailed solution then

read https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination--wp-24873